# Finding the square root of a Laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, eigensystem

Suppose the following matrix $A$ is given
$$ \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0.500 & -0.333 & -0.167\\
-0.500 & 0.667 & -0.167\\
-0.500 & -0.333 & 0.833\end{array}\right]$$
with its transpose $A^T$. The product $A^TA=G$ yields
$$ \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0.750 & -0.334 & -0.417\\
-0.334 & 0.667 & -0.333\\
-0.417 & -0.333 & 0.750\end{array}\right]$$,

where $G$ is a **Laplacian matrix**. Note that matrices $A$ and $G$ are of rank 2, with the zero 
eigenvalue corresponding to eigenvector $1_n=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array}\right]^T$.

I wonder what would be the way to obtain $A$ if only $G$ is given. I tried
eigendecomposition $G=UEU^T$, and then set $A'=UE^{1/2}$, but obtained different result. I guess this has to do with rank deficiency. Could someone explain this? Clearly, the above example is for illustration; you could consider general Laplacian matrix decomposition of the above form.

---

Since, for instance, Cholesky decomposition could be used to find $G=LL^T$, the decomposition on $G$ could yield many solution. I'm interested in the solution that could be expressed as $$A=(I-1_nw^{T}),$$ where $I$ is a $3\times 3$ identity matrix, $1_n=[1~ 1~ 1]$, and $w$ being some vector satisfying $w^T1_n=1$. If it simplifies matters, you could assume that the entries of $w$ are non-negative.

Comment: I think the comment you added about the representation of $A$ is only partially helpful. It assumes that there is exactly one eigenvalue equal to zero, but the non-determinancy is always there, isn't it?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I'm trying to figure out the meaning of "non-determinancy". If that is $det(A)=0$, it holds for the above example, and I'm not sure if it can be generalized for $A=I-1_nw^T$. However, except for $n=3$, I doubt that the solution would always exist.

Comment: No, what I meant is that the solution to your problem isn't uniquely determined. I was pointing out the fact that whether the matrix has a zero eigenvalue or not doesn't actually change the fact that the square root problem has no unique solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have the matrix Laplacian matrix $G=A^TA$ which has a set of eigenvalues $\lambda_0\leq\lambda_1\leq\ldots\leq \lambda_n$ for $G\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ where we always know $\lambda_0 = 0$. Thus the Laplacian matrix is always symmetric positive semi-definite. Because the matrix $G$ is not symmetric positive definite we have to be careful when we discuss the Cholesky decomposition. The Cholesky decomposition exists for a positive semi-definite matrix but it is no longer unique. For example, the positive semi-definite matrix 
$$
 A=\left[\!\!\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
\end{array}
\!\!\right],
$$
has infinitely many Cholesky decompositions
$$
 A=\left[\!\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
\end{array}
\!\right]
=
 \left[\!\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0 \\
  \sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{array}
\!\right]
 \left[\!\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & \sin\theta \\
  0 & \cos\theta
\end{array}
\!\right]=LL^T.
$$

However, because we have a matrix $G$ that is known to be a Laplacian matrix we can actually avoid the more sophisticated linear algebra tools like Cholesky decompositions or finding the square root of the positive semi-definite matrix $G$ such that we recover $A$. For example, if we have the Laplace matrix $G\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$,
$$
G=\left[\!\begin{array}{cccc}
 3 & -1 &  -1 &  -1\\
-1 &  1 & 0 &  0 \\
 -1 & 0 &  1 & 0 \\
 -1 &  0 & 0 &  1 \\
\end{array}\!\right]
$$
we can use graph theory to recover the desired matrix $A$. We do so by formulating the oriented incidence matrix. If we define the number of edges in the graph to be $m$ and the number of vertices to be $n$ then the oriented incidence matrix $A$ will be an $m\times n$ matrix given by 
$$
A_{ev} = \left\{\begin{array}{lc}
  1 &  \textrm{if }e=(v,w)\textrm{ and }v<w  \\
  -1 & \textrm{if }e=(v,w)\textrm{ and }v>w \\
  0 & \textrm{otherwise},
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $e=(v,w)$ denotes the edge which connects the vertices $v$ and $w$. If we take a graph for $G$ with four vertices and three edges,
then we have the oriented incidence matrix 
$$
A = \left[\!\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & -1 & 0 &  0\\
 1 &  0 & -1 &  0 \\
 1 & 0 &  0 & -1 \\
\end{array}\!\right],
$$
and we can find that $G=A^TA$. For the matrix problem you describe you would construct a graph for $G$ with the same number of edges as vertices, then you should have the ability to reconstruct the matrix $A$ when you are only given the Laplacian matrix $G$.

**Update:**

If we define the diagonal matrix of vertex degrees of a graph as $N$ and the adjacency matrix of the graph as $M$, then the Laplacian matrix $G$ of the graph is defined by $G=N-M$. For example, in the following graph

[image]

we find the Laplacian matrix is
$$
G=\left[\!\begin{array}{cccc}
 3 & 0 &  0 &  0\\
 0 &  1 & 0 &  0 \\
 0 & 0 &  1 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &  1 \\
\end{array}\!\right] - \left[\!\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 &  1 &  1\\
 1 &  0 & 0 &  0 \\
 1 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
 1 &  0 & 0 &  0 \\
\end{array}\!\right].
$$
Now we relate the $G$ to the oriented incidence matrix $A$ using the edges and nodes given in the pictured graph. Again we find the entries of $A$ from 
$$
A_{ev} = \left\{\begin{array}{lc}
  1 &  \textrm{if }e=(v,w)\textrm{ and }v<w  \\
  -1 & \textrm{if }e=(v,w)\textrm{ and }v>w \\
  0 & \textrm{otherwise},
\end{array}
\right..
$$ 
For example, edge $e_1$ connects the nodes $v_1$ and $v_2$. So to determine $A_{e_1,v_1}$ we note that the index of $v_1$ is less than the index of $v_2$ (or we have the case $v<w$ in the definition of $A_{ev}$). Thus, $A_{e_1,v_1} = 1$. Similarly by the way of comparing indices we can find $A_{e_1,v_2} = -1$. We give $A$ below in a more explicit way referencing the edges and vertices pictured.
$$
A = \begin{array}{c|cccc}
 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\ \hline
 e_1 & 1 & -1 & 0 &  0\\
 e_2 & 1 &  0 & -1 &  0 \\
 e_3 & 1 & 0 &  0 & -1 \\
\end{array}.
$$

Next, we generalize the concept of the Laplacian matrix to a weighted undirected graph. Let $Gr$ be an undirected finite graph defined by $V$ and $E$ its vertex and edge set respectively. To consider a weighted graph we define a weight function 
$$
w: V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+,
$$
which assigns a non-negative real weight to each edge of the graph. We will denote the weight attached to edge connecting vertices $u$ and $v$ by $w(u,v)$. In the case of a weighted graph we define the degree of each vertex $u\in V$ as the sum of all the weighted edges connected to $u$, i.e.,
$$
d_u = \sum_{v\in V}w(u,v).
$$
From the given graph $Gr$ we can define the weighted adjacency matrix $Ad(Gr)$ as an $n\times n$ with rows and columns indexed by $V$ whose entries are given by $w(u,v)$. Let $D(Gr)$ be the diagonal matrix indexed by $V$ with the vertex degrees on the diagonal then we can find the weighted Laplacian matrix $G$ just as before
$$
G = D(Gr) - Ad(Gr).
$$

In the problem from the original post we know 
$$
G=\left[\!\begin{array}{ccc}
 \tfrac{3}{4} & -\tfrac{1}{3} &  -\tfrac{5}{12} \\
-\tfrac{1}{3} &  \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{3}  \\
 -\tfrac{5}{12} & -\tfrac{1}{3} &  \tfrac{3}{4}  \\
\end{array}\!\right].
$$ 
From the comments we know we seek a factorization for $G$ where $G=A^TA$ and specify $A$ is of the form $A=I-1_nw^T$ where $w^T1_n=1$. For full generality assume the matrix $A$ has no zero entries. Thus if we formulate the weighted oriented incidence matrix to find $A$ we want the weighted adjacency matrix $Ad(Gr)$ to have no zero entries as well, i.e., the weighted graph will have loops. Actually calculating the weighted oriented incidence matrix seems difficult (although it may simply be a result of my inexperience with weighted graphs). However, we can find a factorization of the form we seek in an ad hoc way if we assume we know something about the loops in our graph. We split the weighted Laplacian matrix $G$ into the degree and adjacency matrices as follows
$$
G=\left[\!\begin{array}{ccc}
 \tfrac{5}{4} & 0 &  0 \\
0 &  1 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 &  \tfrac{11}{12}  \\
\end{array}\!\right]-\left[\!\begin{array}{ccc}
 \tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{3} &  \tfrac{5}{12} \\
\tfrac{1}{3} &  \tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{1}{3}  \\
 \tfrac{5}{12} & \tfrac{1}{3} &  \tfrac{1}{6}  \\
\end{array}\!\right] = D(Gr)-Ad(Gr).
$$
Thus we know the loops on $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ have weights $1/2$, $1/3$, and $1/6$ respectively. If we put the weights on the loops into a vector $w$ = $[\frac{1}{2}$ $\frac{1}{3}$ $\frac{1}{6}]^T$ then we can recover the matrix $A$ we want in the desired form
$$
A = I-1_nw^T = \left[\!\begin{array}{ccc}
 \tfrac{1}{2} & -\tfrac{1}{3} &  -\tfrac{1}{6} \\
-\tfrac{1}{2} &  \tfrac{2}{3} & -\tfrac{1}{6}  \\
 -\tfrac{1}{2} & -\tfrac{1}{3} &  \tfrac{5}{6}  \\
\end{array}\!\right].
$$

It appears if we have knowledge of the loops in our weighted graph we can find the matrix $A$ in the desired form. Again, this was done in an ad hoc manner (as I am not a graph theorist) so it may be a hack that worked just for this simple problem.

Comment: Recovering $A$ in the case of Laplacian $G$ as you describe should not be a problem (in you example, only one row/column contain non-zero elements). I guess the matters complicate with the general "full" Laplacian as in my example. Given the $O(n^2)$ degrees of freedom of $G$, I'm not sure if the solution could be obtained, subject to constraints I give above.

Comment: Right, the example $G$ I give is highly simplified but it will be possible in the general case where $G$ is a full matrix. The graph theory problem becomes more complicated as you increase the number of edges and vertices. In essence we replace a difficult matrix factorization problem with a difficult graph theory problem.

Comment: Ok, I would appreciate if you try to reconstruct $A$ as is given above from given $G$.

Comment: @AndrewWinters: Could you clarify how $A$ is determined from $G$? It's not clear to me how your algorithm proceeds in the general case.

Comment: @AndrewWinters: Just have in mind the decomposition form I'm looking for, $A=I-1_nw$, $w^T1_n=1$. For $n>3$, one would have hard time decomposing given $G$ to get such $A$.

Comment: @usero I updated my post to address the problem in your original post. You're correct that getting the decomposition form may be difficult (I was only able to obtain it if I assumed I knew something about the structure of the weighted graph).

Comment: Still, with $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ degrees of freedom of some $G$, the solution with $n$ degrees of freedom of $w$ might not always exist (or?). The decomposition you posted is fine; you could get it easier by just considering $A$ from the very beginning of my question. Would you be able to do so for some general $G$? Is it _hard_ or _not always possible_?

Comment: I don't think it will be possible for a general $G$ as it seems that the specific factorization form $A=I-1_nw^T$ will only exist for certain types of weighted graphs. So the Laplacian matrices $G$ that are of the form $G=A^TA=(I-1_nw^T)^T(I-1_nw^T)$ are a subset of all possible Laplacian matrices.

Comment: Same conclusion I made. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Is there such a factorization for the cotangent Laplacian used in mesh analysis?

Answer (score 9):

I think that you are confusing the *unique* matrix square-root of Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix $A$, i.e., a Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix $B$ satisfying,

$$
B^2 = A,
$$

with the *non-unique* problem of finding a matrix $C$ satisfying

$$
C^H C = A,
$$

where clearly the mapping $C \mapsto Q C$, for *any* unitary $Q$, preserves the identity. As you noticed, a Cholesky factorization provides one possible solution. However, **note that Cholesky only works for Hermitian positive-definite matrices** (with the possible exception of a Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix which is positive-definite if the last row and column are removed).

Lastly, one can constructively define the *unique* matrix square-root of a Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix through its eigenvalue decomposition, say

$$
A = U \Lambda U^H,
$$

where $U$ is unitary and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with non-negative entries due to $A$ being positive semi-definite. The Hermitian matrix square-root can easily be identified as

$$
B = U \sqrt{\Lambda} U^H.
$$

Comment: You're right about the _matrix square-root_. Clearly, there are different ways to achieve the factorization, but could guarantee that $A$ (from my quest.) could be written as I formulated.

Answer (score 6):

In essence, what you're asking is to find the square root A of a matrix G, so that $$G = A^T A.$$ There are many ways to do that if $G$ is a symmetric matrix. For example, if $G$ is symmetric, then the Cholesky decomposition $G=L^TL$ provides you with one answer: $A=L$. But you already found another answer, with the matrix $A$ you already have. What this simply means is that there are many "square roots" of the matrix $G$, and if you want to have one particular one, you need to rephrase the question in such a way that you specify the structural properties of the "branch" of the square root that you're interested in.

I would say that this situation is not dissimilar to taking the square root among the real numbers using the complex numbers: there, too, in general you have two roots, and you have to say which one you want to make the answer unique.

Comment: You're definitely right. Another way would be the spectral decomposition approach as I state above. I've made an edit to make the solution unique. Hopefully it won't complicate matters.

Comment: Is a solution with the constraint I give above always existent? Perhaps it holds only for some cases, and not in general.

Comment: Actually, Cholesky does not work in his case, as it (essentially) requires that the matrix is Hermitian positive-definite.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can apply $LDL^{T}$ factorization for your matrix A. Since your matrix has non-negative eigenvalues, the diagonal matrix D will have non-negative entries along the diagonl. Then you can easily factorize $\hat{D} = \sqrt{D}$. And you get the matrix $G = L\hat{D}$. The eigendecomposition is not numerically stable, so I think you should avoid this kind of decomposition.

Comment: I have to disagree on two counts: (1) $LDL^T$ factorization does not work for singular matrices (his matrix is singular), and (2) eigenvalue decompositions of Hermitian matrices *are* considered stable, as their eigenvector matrices are unitary.

Comment: @JackPoulson I try a singular matrix A in matlab, and run ldl, it works. The zero eigenvalues corresponds to the zeros in the diagonal of D.

Comment: I think that you will find that MATLAB's 'ldl' routine computes a *block* $LDL^T$ decomposition *with pivoting*, i.e., $PAP'=LDL^T$, where $D$ is not required to be diagonal (it can have $2 \times 2$ blocks). In order to avoid division by zero due to the matrix being singular, the zero diagonal entries are pivoted to the bottom-right of the matrix.